# Ansible: loading a group variable conditionally on a count

Tags: rackspace-cloud, ansible

```
1 - name: Test
2 - hosts: webserv
3   connection: local
4   gather_facts: False
5 
6   tasks:
7   - name: Provision web instances
8     local_action:
9         module: rax
10         credentials: "{{ rax_cred | mandatory }}"
11         name: "{{ rax_name | default(w0) }}"
12         flavor: "{{ rax_flavor | default(6) }}"
13         image: debian-7-wheezy-pvhvm
14         files:
15           /root/.ssh/authorized_keys: "{{ rax_ssh_keys | mandatory }}"
16         count: "{{ rax_count | default(1) }}"
17         group: "{{ rax_group }}"
18         region: DFW
19         wait: yes
20         state: present
21     register: rax
```

I have this ansible-playbook, but because of the group the name of the new server gets a number counter attached to it. I want to be able to use this for a single server instance as well as for several ones. Is there a way I can do something like:

if count is more than 1, then have the group variable set.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to have the `group` value set only if the `rax_count` is greater than 1. You have to do this in two plays:

```
- name: Provision web instances
     local_action:
         module: rax
         credentials: "{{ rax_cred | mandatory }}"
         name: "{{ rax_name | default(w0) }}"
         flavor: "{{ rax_flavor | default(6) }}"
         image: debian-7-wheezy-pvhvm
         files:
           /root/.ssh/authorized_keys: "{{ rax_ssh_keys | mandatory }}"
         count: "{{ rax_count | default(1) }}"
         group: "{{ rax_group if rax_count > 1 else None }}"
         region: DFW
         wait: yes
         state: present
     register: rax
```

Comment: I did it with include files, but used the same logic. Is there a way to modify only that variable?

Comment: Sorry but I'm not quite sure what you're asking, could you rephrase/elaborate?

Comment: You have answered my question, but it requires repeating a lot of code. I was wondering if I can set only the group variable based on the count number. If count>1 then have the group variable, else don't have it.

Comment: You can try it like this - `group: {{ rax_group if rax_count > 1 else None }}`

Comment: I will give it a try and let you know. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for accepting. Updated the answer to include the improvement